# Click tracking with sendGrids @sendgrid/mail npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, click-tracking

I'm using the @sendgrid/mail library and am trying to enable click tracking inside of my msg config object but the only documentation I have been able to find is to set `trackingSettings: {}`. What additional properties need to be set in order to turn click tracking on within the `trackingSettings` object?

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit late I know, but I've come across your question while searching for the same topic.

**Here's how you do it:**

```
trackingSettings: {
  clickTracking: {
    enable: true
  },
  openTracking: {
    enable: true
  },
  subscriptionTracking: {
    enable: true
  }
}
```

---

*You can check out more advanced use cases of the library here:*

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md